# Why does Server 2003 not have System Restore?

Tags: windows-server-2003, system-restore

There are numerous articles about [how to enable System Restore on Windows Server 2003](http://www.google.ca/search?q=enable%20System%20Restore%20Windows%20Server%202003). My question is, why is it not there in the first place? One would think a service like this is even more important on a server where long term stability is paramount than on a workstation.

Comment: For servers we make actual backups, and generally test things before installing on the server.  Desktop users, do a poor job making backups, and don't usually have a testing environment.

Comment: Because it's the devil.

Comment: I debated on just saying, "That's crazy talk"...

Comment: Long term stability is paramount on a server, you're absolutely why. This is why hack jobs that were designed for home use are not enabled on the server by default or by most sane sysadmins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are probably lots of different reasons why it's not enabled.

My reason is that System Restore isn't the panacea that you think it is.  You're restoring a computer back to a specific state (of the whole OS) at a particular point in time.  Can you imagine the problems that could cause should you enable this on a server running AD or perhaps DNS or DHCP?

IMHO it's the exact opposite of "long term stability".

As for 2003 servers, that's what the Volume Shadow Copy Service is for...restoring specific *data* back to a specific date/time.

**Edited to add**

System Restore also has the potential to make someone lazy (and lull them into a false sense of security) with regard to patches, installing software, etc.  Generally with servers, more care needs to be taken when installing aforementioned items.  Patches and software need to be tested before pushing them to production servers.  The same kind of care doesn't necessarily have to be taken on workstations..

Comment: System Restore is a "Good Enough" type operation. It's good enough to get a WinXP workstation up and running long enough to back up all the data the user should have been backing up all along and then do a wipe and reimage. For a server where you want 24/7 reliablity, it's a stability liablity (what's restored is pretty ugly) and a waste of disk space.

Comment: Don't even get me started on System Restore archiving viruses...

Comment: Oh, gosh, didn't think of that one. When that happens, just disable System Restore and let it flush all the backups. Had one with about 15 saved copies of the original viral content. Sweet!

Comment: I see it didn't think it through. I've always used System Restore on my workstation as a testing device: install this app, look at what it does, make some notes, back out the change, all usually in that same day. This is what my planned method was on the server. I guess what I'm really wondering about is "what is the equivalent of Source Code Control for a running machine?", which is a totally different question, and we probably wont see for years, if ever. ;-)

Comment: There are numerous things you can do.  What I do is use something like Backup Exec, which not ONLY backs up System State, but is product aware..for things like Exchange, SQL Server, etc.  I'm not shilling BE, just mentioning it because I've used it in the past.

Comment: The thing you have to remember about backing up production servers is - forget everything you know about backing up desktops. You'll have to put a lot of thought into acceptable risk and go from there.  I've seen backup solutions cost nothing all the way up to thousands of dollars per year...based on acceptable risk..

Answer (score 2):

Lots of features are left off by default.

I personally think this is a good thing.  It makes me research and understand ramifications of turning up some service or feature.

For instance, while I agree about the usefulness of System Restore, it does use resources, and it may not work as advertised.  Do I want some well meaning engineer (or more likely, a marketing guy or gal) decide that it should be on by default?

Again, I think that when a vendor makes me understand what I am turning on, rather than deciding that they know better, is a good thing.

Comment: This is a pretty "Rambly" answer. I **think** I understand what you're getting at but it's pretty hard to pull that out of the noise. I'd suggest removing the rambling and irrelevant bits, just leaving a clear concise answer.

Comment: Well done. Downvote removed. :)

Answer (score 2):

System Restore was only added to Windows to cut down on support calls by giving users a way to undo their most recent screw-up. While this might still be useful for a server in a lab or test environment it makes no sense at all in a production environment. Any admin caught enabling it on a production server should be rapidly escorted off the premises because their methodology is questionable at best.

Comment: Propbably the most honest answer.